# Distance between a point in $3$-D and the line $x=0$ ($y$-axis)

Tags: geometry

Find the the perpendicular distance (which I assume will be the shortest distance both in $3$-D and $2$-D (if not then please find both perpendicular distance and shortest distance) of the $y$-axis ($x= 0$) and the point $P(3,2,4)$.

Finding such things in $2$-D is a piece of cake. Anyone can do it really. But when I enter $3$-D things start going confusing for me. Is this a very simple question or is there a standard formula for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to find the (shortest) distance between a point and a line in $3$-space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892612/easiest-way-to-find-the-shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-in-3-sp)

Comment: Note that $x=0$ defines a *plane* in three-dimensions, and the $y$-axis is described by a combination of equations $x=0,z=0$.  Taking the latter as the intended meaning, based on the body of the Question, it should be evident that the closest point on the $y$-axis to point $P(3,2,4)$ is....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If $P=(3,2,4)$ than the perpendicular distance (that is also the shorter distance) from the $y$ axis stay on the plane $y=2$ that is perpendicular to the $y$ axis and contains the point.
So it is the distance from the point $P$ and the point $Q=(0,2,0)$.

Can you find this distance from two points?

Comment: Thanx bro!! That makes it way too easy

Comment: Distance = {(x1 - x2)^2 +(y2-y1)^2 +(z2-z1^)}^1/2.

Comment: Yes... so the distance is $d=5$... and don't forget to accept if you like the answer.. :)

Comment: That makes the distance as 5. I really need to strengthen my geometry.This should have been thought by me. Thank's again though :)